# change the first word of string to the first letter

Tags: python, string

I want to change the first word of a string to the first letter of that word. For organisms, you can write "Arabidopsis thaliana" or "A. thaliana".
Because the String names are sometimes too long for my purpose I want to change this, so the string becomes shorter.

I tried to find a similar question, but it is always removing the first word or make the first letter uppercase or replacing the first word with a specific character, but never with the first character of the word itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `replace()` :

```
>>> s = 'Arabidopsis thaliana'
>>> s.replace(s.split()[0], s[0])
'A thaliana'
```

In the rare case, according to mrCarnivore if the first word is occurring multiple times we could use `maxreplace` parameter

```
>>> s = 'Arabidopsis Arabidopsis thaliana'
>>> s.replace(s.split()[0], s[0], 1)
'A Arabidopsis bologna'
```

Comment: In the (rare?) case that the first word is occurring multiple times in the string your solution would replace all those words with the first letter and not only the first word in the string.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I have added the solution for multiple occurrence as well, pls check

Comment: Thanks, this one is a bit more understandable. I guess that if I really needed to replace the second word, I could do the same, only with s.split[1] and s[3] after changing the s variable with your solution. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
s = 'Arabidopsis thaliana bologna'

l = s.split()
s2 = l[0][0] + '. ' + ' '.join(l[1:])
print(s2)
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply and it works! But I tried to make "A. t. bologna" as well in case I need it, but using something line s3 = s2.split()[1][0] + '. ' + ' '.join(s2.split()[1:]) or other variations do not give me the desired results. I dont fully understand what is happening in your solution

Comment: @Fini you're moving the goalposts. Dont expect answerers to follow along with you whilst you take them on a journey of changing requirements.